# Verifying that a function is smooth

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Let $M,N$ be smooth manifolds and a function $f:M\to N$.

By definition, $f$ is smooth when $\psi\circ f\circ\varphi^{-1}$ is smooth for every chart $\varphi$ of $M$ and $\psi$ of $N$.

But I've noticed this: for different charts $\widetilde{\varphi}$ of $M$ and $\widetilde{\psi}$ of $N$, we have that $\widetilde{\psi}\circ\psi^{-1}$, $\varphi\circ\widetilde{\varphi}^{-1}$ are smooth, and that:

$$\widetilde{\psi}\circ f\circ\widetilde{\varphi}^{-1}=(\widetilde{\psi}\circ\psi^{-1})\circ(\psi\circ f\circ\varphi^{-1})\circ(\varphi\circ\widetilde{\varphi}^{-1})$$

So if we know $\psi\circ f\circ\varphi^{-1}$ is smooth, it follows that $\widetilde{\psi}\circ f\circ\widetilde{\varphi}^{-1}$ is smooth. So it seems that I've shown that:

> In order to check whether $f$ is smooth, it's enough to take *only one* chart $\varphi$ of $M$ and *only one* chart $\psi$ of $N$ and verify that $\psi\circ f\circ\varphi^{-1}$ is smooth.

This looks very strange, because if this is true, I only need to know $M,N$ locally in order to conclude something about $f$, which generally involves $M,N$ globally.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you need to be more careful with the domain and targets of all the maps involved, because sometimes, it is possible that if $(U,\phi)$ is a chart on $M$ and $(V,\psi)$ is a chart on $N$ then $f(U) \cap V = \emptyset$ so it doesn't really make sense to speak of $\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$. Also, if two charts on the same manifold, like $(U,\phi)$ and $(U',\phi')$ have disjoint domains: $U \cap U' = \emptyset$ then the transition map $\phi' \circ \phi^{-1}$ doesn't really make sense. So, in your argument, you need to be careful with domains so the compositions make sense.

Comment: @peek-a-boo, I see. Once I fix charts $(U\varphi), (V,\psi)$, I'm necessarily restricting myself to subsets of $U,V$. Introducing $\widetilde{\varphi}, \widetilde{\psi}$ will only impose more restrictions to those subsets, so I'm only examining $f$ locally. In order to understand $f$ completely, I really have to consider all charts. Right?

Comment: yes that's right. However what (a more careful version of) your reasoning shows is that to check smoothness, rather than checking for all charts in the maximal atlas, it suffices to check the smoothness relative to a collection of charts which cover $M$ and $N$. said differently, it's enough to choose an atlas for M and an atlas for N and check smoothness relative to these atlases (this is a much easier task because often, we can construct atlases with very few charts)

Comment: Differential topology is defined by maximal atlases only because if we allowed any atlas, two differential topologies could be different, but still define exactly the same topology and concept of smoothness (because the atlases were compatible), which is not desirable. By using maximal atlases, then if the atlases differ, some maps will be smooth under one, but not under the other.